# What exactly does it mean that the states are protected by the symmetry?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, topological-insulators

I am trying to understand symmetries in the case of topological insulators. And I have a huge problem with the interpretation of symmetries. Let's say we consider quantum spin Hall state, where we consider edge states -- spin up electrons moving along one direction and spin down electrons moving opposite. And as I can read -- edge states are protected by the time-reversal symmetry. So, as time-reversal symmetry changes momentum and spin, we can transform spin-up to spin-down electrons and vice versa.

But I totally have no idea what does it mean that these states are protected? How should I interpret this?

Comment: I am not expert but I think that "protected" refers to the fact that if you include some disorder in the system (e.g. a random local potential), the edge states survive. So this is a way to say that the edge states are not an accident of the specific Hamiltonian, but are robust as far as the symmetry is there.

Comment: I agree with Matteo - the *state is protected against perturbations.* It is present there as long as the symmetry exists, even though, e.g., potential may significantly change. See, e.g., the answer in tread [What is the difference between symmetry protected topological (SPT) order and topological order?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312256/247642) (possibly a duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way to frame that would be that the *gaplessness* (or sometimes *degeneracy*, for example in the SSH model) of the boundary modes is protected by the symmetry.

For a generic gapless system or system with ground state degeneracy, we expect that adding some local perturbation will gap the system out and destroy the gaplessness / degeneracy. This is because perturbations generally introduce non-zero matrix elements in your Hamiltonian connecting the states with similar energies, and this opens up a gap (try this for yourself using a two-state degenerate Hamiltonian). Therefore, when you have a not fine-tuned lattice model which is gapless or ground state degenerate, you need to explain why it is so.

One example of such a system is an SPT with a symmetric boundary. The statement says that, as long as the boundary preserves the symmetry, the system remains gapless (degenerate) and any local perturbation will not open up a gap. This is a non-trivial statement for the reasons explained in the previous paragraph. The reasoning behind this statement may be beyond the scope of this question (and I believe the general case is an open problem): one way to understand it is by noting that the boundary behaves as an anomalous quantum field theory in the low-energy limit, and this anomaly is induced by the bulk. This phenomenon is called anomaly inflow / bulk-boundary correspondence in the context of SPTs.